# Listing every objects that extends a trait

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I would like to know how I can list every objects that extend a given trait.

For instance I have :

```
trait MyTrait

object MyTObjA extends MyTrait

object MyTObjB extends MyTrait
```

and what I want to achieve is something like that without having to list all these objects myself :

```
val myTraitObjects: Seq[Type] = Seq(typeOf[MyTObjA], typeOf[MyTObjB])
```

Comment: Note: If your trait is not sealed, it is only possible to find all of its implementations by typechecking the entire classpath.